# Random variables $X$ and $Y$ that are not independent

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to solve a stat question, here is the question:

Give an example of two random variables $X$ and $Y$, each taking values in the set $\{1,2,3\}$ such that $P(X = 1; Y = 1) = P(X = 1)P(Y = 1)$, but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

A friend says that the answer is:
$$P(X=1,Y=1)=P(X=1,Y=2)=P(X=2,Y=1)=P(X=3,Y=3)=\frac{1}{4}$$
I don't quite get why that is the case. Where did $1/4$ come from?

Thanks

Comment: Note that the sum of all probabilities should be $1$.

Comment: I know that. But, I don't get why there isn't the case for P(X=2,Y=2), P(X=1,Y=3)....etc

Comment: It is obvious that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent in the given answer. Furthermore, $$P(X=1)=P(Y=1)=\frac{1}{2}$$ and $$P(X=1;Y=1)=\frac{1}{4},$$ so the first criterion is also satisfied.

Comment: I'm sorry, I might sound stupid, but how is P(X=1)=1/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that

$$P(X=1)=P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=1,Y=2)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}$$

and

$$P(Y=1)=P(X=1,Y=1)+P(X=2,Y=1)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Furthermore, $$P(X=1;Y=1)=\frac{1}{4},$$ so the first criterion is satisfied.

Also, since $X=3$ implies $Y=3$, it is obvious that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent in the given answer.

The value $1/4$ was chosen so that the sum of all probabilities is $1$.